# How can i generate a fixed random numbers in c#?

Tags: c#-2.0

I need to randomize fixed numbers, for example, 1,3,5,7,10. My output will be only 1,3,5,7 or 10. Please Help me! Thanks! Is there a way to randomize fixed numbers or user inputted numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Get a random number from 0-4, then select from a dictionary of `{ 1, 3, 5, 7, 10 }`.

```
int[] select = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 10 };
var rand = new Random();
int num = select[rand.Next(5)];
```

Comment: can i use this on string, char? :)

Comment: Sorry i am new to this, but how will my code be? What is my code?

Comment: I did it! Thanks! I can now finish my work. Thanks dbaseman! :)